# Notification from GitLab project to Microsoft Teams chats?

Tags: gitlab, microsoft-teams, webhooks

Is there any way to send notifications of any issue raised on a GitLab project to individual chats and not channels in Microsoft Teams?

I am unable to find a way to integrate it with Teams chat. The only integration I can see is via channels and that's not what I need.

Comment: Currently we can send notification messages to channel only and not to individual chats.